# Suggestions for exporting big dataset to excel from search results

Tags: rest

I have the following scenario

```
Client Site colleciton
   Job Site 1
      Document Library X
         Document of Content Type X.docx
   Job Site 2
      Document Library X
        ---nodocumenthere---
```

We have 20,000 site collections, and 9000 job sites.

With the search api, I can run a query easily to return all results I need.

I was thinking on implementing this with a visual webpart and use Datatables:
http://www.datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

The problem is that as far as I know the REST api returns only 500 rows, and this cant be overwritten.

I also need to be able to export the entire dataset to excel, so users can process it offline.

What would be your suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call REST API getting an count of number of items, then make a call using REST API multiple times. Like in range of 1-500, then 500-1000...this will be in loop and after getting it stored in javascript object, you can export it into excel using activeXobject in IE or other library are available to export in other browsers.

If you are doing server side, then you can get the items more than 2000 at a item then export to excel using OpenXml. To export item more than 2000, read Microsoft white paper to fetch item for more than 2000, that will help you

Answer (score 2):

How fresh should the data be?

If you have 1 day, then you can run a console application every night and store it to a list or (better) in an sql server. Then, asp.net datatable should be able to do what you want to do. If you want more search capabilities, I would suggest telerik  radgrid.
A web part : http://sharepoint.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/web-parts/Pages/Single-List-Binding.aspx or radgrid: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/grid/examples/performance/linq/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Although DataTables is appealing (I was looking at it myself for displaying search results), if you're really just looking to export the results, why not use a webpart (visual or otherwise) that has a search query box, displays the rows in a datatable, and has a button to export it using serverside code into a library ?

Btw, DataTables doesn't really export to excel, it creates a CSV.

Why not use something like [ClosedXML](https://closedxml.codeplex.com/) or if you don't mind it being a CSV, [KBcsv](http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/)

It's pretty "easy" I dare say, especially the CSV option.

It's also pretty easy to page over all the results server side and export the full set of results. Look at the [KeywordQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.search.query.keywordquery.aspx) class for details.